# Getting list of fields detected from Invoice Parser google Document AI Processor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

Invoice Parser documentation lists the fields that this processor attempts to find in a document.
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list?hl=en_US#processor_invoice-processor

I am only interested in some of the fields in the Invoice processor, is there a way to get the list of fields and request the processor to find the data points for a selected set of fields?

E.g. I am only interested in invoice_date and invoice_id. So, the processor only finds these two fields for me and does not waste its time finding others.

I found an endpoint that retrieves the processor's details but it does not get the field list.
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/projects.locations.processors/get

This process endpoint does not have anything to specify the fields that I am interested in.
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/projects.locations.processors/process

My research indicates that this feature does not exist, hoping someone tells me that I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible to limit the specific entities that are extracted by a specialized processor. The processor will always processes the entire document and extract everything it can find.

However, a new parameter has recently been added to the [`process`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.processors/process) method in the REST API that lets you provide a [`fieldMask`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.processors/process#:%7E:text=Default%20to%20false.-,fieldMask,-string%20(FieldMask) to limit the fields that will be returned in the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) object. This has also been added to the [How-to Guide for making a processing request](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#:%7E:text=for%20more%20information.-,FIELD_MASK,-%3A%20Specifies%20which%20fields). Currently, this only works for the REST API (not client libraries) and online processing.

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it can significantly limit the size of the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) response if you don't need fields like [`content`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#:%7E:text=for%20more%20info.-,content,-string%20(bytes)